# pdf viewed with Adobe Acrobat displays box with URL link generated with hyperref preceded by local path to current file

Tags: hyperref, pdftex, adobe

I want (if at all possible) to suppress display of the path to the current open pdf file generated by pdflatex in a link generated with package `hyperref`. The problem occurs when the pdf is viewed with `Adobe Acrobat Reader XI` on `Win8.1`, not with TeXworks. To clarify, when the mouse hovers over a link on the pdf the url pops up in a box, but also shown is the path to the current pdf file. How to get rid of the local path text??

An example:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\href{ http://www.kleptocrat.edu}{Prof.Gas Bag}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue with a standard class, such as `article`? If not, please provide a link to the class as it is not in TeX Live.

Comment: @cfr Thanks, I made the change to the doc class - your answer is spot on!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not introducing a spurious space before the url in the first argument to `\href` seems to solve the problem. I say 'seems' because I do not have access to that version of Reader or to Windows. Hence, I tested this with an older version on GNU/Linux. However, I reproduced the problem and tested the solution, so I'm guessing it is the same. (If not, let me know and I'll delete this answer.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\href{http://www.kleptocrat.edu}{Prof.Gas Bag}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Fud!! That's right, it was such a small space I missed it... embarrasing but perhaps worth leaving since there may be others with who'll run into this...

Comment: @TryHard Not really embarrassing. At least, maybe it is in the sense that you really are embarrassed. But not in the sense that you should be! Stuff happens. Besides, it is not obvious to me why this causes Reader to show the local file name, but Okular, say, not to do so.