# \href links are broken with Adobe Reader

Tags: xetex, hyperref, pdf, document-classes, adobe

I encountered a problem lately that I can't find a reason for. I wrote a command "infopage" which is placed in my .cls-File and does look like the following:

```
\newcommand{\infopage}[2]{%
 \chapter*{#1}
 \Large\textbf{#1}
 \vspace*{1cm}
 \normalsize #2
}
```

Now I wanted to use this command in my .tex-File:

```
\infopage{Impressum}{%
...
Kontakt\linebreak
\href{mymail@test.com}{mymail@test.com}
\href{https://www.google.com}{google.com}
}
```

So far, so good. I compile it with XeLaTeX and there are no errors. When I try and open the PDF now with Adobe Acrobat Reader DC and hover over the links, I notice, that the mail link is incorrect (it adds some kind of local path to the tex file's position in front of the url/mail address). The second link (to a website) works properly.

I read about a similar problem [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218327/) where the problem was an additional space in the link. I have the feeling that maybe the `\linebreak` is badly used here, I need the linebreak at this position, though.

Comment: The URL for the mail link is wrong, the proper URL is `mailto:mymail@test.com`, most likely Adobe Reader is trying to do some scanning on the file in order to present sertain URLs as clickable URLs even if they are not marked as links.

Comment: Additionally you are more likely to get help if you provide self contained minimal code others can copy and test as is. Here we have to add document class, preamble etc before we can even test the code.